# How to relate a complex field to another node

Tags: entities, nodes

I'm building a hobby site that is going to be used to record results (golf). A round of golf will have any number of players, selectable from a known list of players.

I would like to be able to create a new round and add players to it, entering a score for each one. My first thought is to create content types for player and round, and a complex field that does something similar to node reference.

Before I went down that path I wanted to see if there was a smarter more Drupal way of doing this. One idea I had was to have a third content type, result, which would be a node reference to a player and an integer field, but this would require having to create the results before hand. Or perhaps the result has a relationship to a round and a player, so the workflow is create a round, then create as many results as required.

The basic question, is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this is as follows:

- I have basic content types of Player and Golf Course.
- When I want to enter new scores, I first create a Round (which is another content
  type with a node reference to a Golf Course and a date field).
- Once the round is created I create Results (another content type which has
  a relationship to a round and a player and an integer for the score).

This handles my data entry requirements even though the workflow is a bit of a kludge, but I can streamline that later I think. Now the next step will be using views to display my results but that will probably be another question :)